# Converting data property to accessor property and vice versa in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I was reading about [[Configurable]] property attribute in JavaScript. From [here](https://2ality.com/2012/10/javascript-properties.html) -

> [[Configurable]] holds a boolean. If false, you cannot delete a
>   property, change any of its attributes (except [[Value]]) or convert
>   between data property and accessor property. In other words,
>   [[Configurable]] controls the writability of a property’s meta-data.

How do you convert from data property to accessor property *and vice versa* that configurable as false might stop us to do the conversion ?

Comment: `let o = { p: "hi" }; Object.defineProperty(o, "p", { get: () => console.log("message") });` If "p" is non-configurable, this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same article:

> `Object.defineProperty(obj, propName, propDesc)`
>   Create or change a property on `obj` whose name is `propName` and whose attributes are specified via `propDesc`

So for example,

```
const o = {example: undefined};
Object.defineProperty(o, "example", {get() {}}); // it's an accessor property now
Object.defineProperty(o, "example", {value: undefined}); // it's a data property again
Object.defineProperty(o, "example", {configurable: false}); // it's not longer configurable
Object.defineProperty(o, "example", {get() {}}); // TypeError: Cannot redefine property
```